# Crosscompiling cpp Shared Object results in "Undefined Symbol" but works for c Setup

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake

I want to crosscompile a shared library (c and cpp code) on my Ubuntu System (x86_64) for Android aarch64. For reasons of simplicity for this example I created only a source and a header file.

The header file **header.hpp** within **/include**

```c
int test();
```

The source file **src.cpp** within **/src**

```c
#include "../include/header.hpp" // #include "../include/header.h"
int test() {
   return 42;
}
```

My **CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE android.toolchain.cmake)
project(testlibrary)

# find header & source
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_CPP "src/*.cpp")#file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_C "src/*.c")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER "include/*.h")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}  SHARED
  ${SOURCE_CPP}
  ${HEADER}
)
```

My **android.toolchain.cmake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++")#set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc")

set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529)
```

After calling my function within my app I receive the following error message:

```
Could not invoke FunctionCaller.test_function

null

Error looking up function 'testFunc': undefined symbol: testFunc
```

Not finding **testFunc** seems to be related to not compiling or correctly linking my **.cpp/.hpp** files I suppose.

Changing my setup from **cpp** to **c** and everything is found and I receive the correct return value.

| C++ | C |
| --- | --- |
| src.cpp | src.c |
| header.hpp | header.c |
| #include "../include/header.hpp" | #include "../include/header.h" |
| file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_CPP "src/*.cpp") | file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_C "src/*.c") |
| set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++") | set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc") |

What am I missing here? I expected it to fail for both configurations since I installed both compilers the same way.

Comment: Perhaps it's a [name magnling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) issue? Declare and define it as `extern "C"` to (among other things) inhibit name mangling.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude I  have another slightly different question, when I now use my code within the .cpp file e.g. ```char *out = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char);``` I receive a ```dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found``` error. But removing this line also removes the error. Is this somewhat related? Using the same snipped on my native system works completely fine.